# Facebook like button not working, suddonly showing zero

Tags: javascript

My blog had 101 likes, but when I saw it now, it is showing zero likes, and when I click on like button, it is not updating.

The Java script which is being used for the button is this,

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://themadeconomy.blogspot.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

site : http://themadeconomy.blogspot.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to change the data-href attribute to match your blogs address? Like this :

```
data-href="http://themadeconomy.blogspot.in"
```

Instead of :

```
data-href="http://themadeconomy.blogspot.com"
```

More about Facebook Like Button [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: Hi Nikos, thanks for the help. I completely regenerated the code in facebook and updated my blog html. Now it's working :)